# Characters between mac and windows in RTC (Rational Team Concert)

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

End of last year we had some issues when someone checked in a file containing characters which caused issues in windows ( ">" and "<").

Due to the special character, rtc automatically seems to rename the files. I checked with another of my colleague, and he used "/" in the filename, which is translated by rtc into a ":". But apparently, this still causes the renaming issue.

My question is now, to avoid such issues between mac and windows in the future, is it not possible to implement a validation rule at the time a file is checked in, to make sure such characters are blocked?